# Determinant of partition matirx

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Let $X$ be $n\times p$ matrix as $X=(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_p)$. I partition the matrix as follows $X=(X_1, X_2)$ where $X_1$ is a $n\times p_1$ matrix and $X_2$ is a $n\times (p-p_1)$ matrix. Then how can I show the following?

$|I+X X^{\prime}|=|I+X_1 X_1^{\prime} +X_2 X_2^{\prime}|$, where $|A|$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$ and $I$ is the identity matrix of order $n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to split it and compute as : $X=(x_1,...,x_{p_1},0,...,0) +(0,...,0,x_{p_1 +1},...,x_p)$

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have tried it as follows: Proving the above question is same as proving $|XX'|=|X_1X_1'+X_2X_2'|$. Now this can be proved easily: |XX'|=|(X_1 X_2)(X_1 X_2)'|=|(X_1X'_1+X_2X'_2)|. Am I correct? Or am I missing something.

Comment: That looks fine. You only need to prove that the matrix $XX'= X_1X_1'+X_2X_2'$.  No need to put the determinants.

Comment: Yes...you are right. Simple thing but missed this.